# Not able to get the values needed from javascript using substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

***Background***

I currently have built a webApi that I used to crawl a SharePoint collection.  I am getting images base64 and all the properties needed via csom.  I am returning all these value via my controller to a word.js app that I am working on.

***Question***

The string value I am getting is `"width=611px;height=262px;"` . As you may be able to tell I am looking to get the width and height from this string and assign them to separate variables.

***Current Approach***

I have had this conversation before concerning Regex and substring and it is widely known that using substring is more efficient than regex expression.  However I wonder if in this case a regex expression will be more effective than using substring?

***Current Code***

```
var Widthtest = contentObject.ImageSize[x].replace("width=", '').replace("height=", '').replace("px", '').replace(";", '').trim();
```

***Current Code Problems***

1. The code example supplied gets the values of both height and width combined in one string.
2. The code example supplied is rudimentary and may cause confusion for other developers

***Desired Result***

My ultimate goal is to have two variables which hold the value of the width and height separately. From a string that follows the same format as  `"width=611px;height=262px;"`

```
var height = height.value;

var width = width.value;
```

Comment: You're better off using a regex than substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to use `regex` to set capturing groups for the two values separately. You can use...

```
var re = /width=(\d{1,4})px;height=(\d{1,4})px;/;
```

...as your `regex`. The pattern assumes that both the `height` and `width` will be between 1 and 4 digits long. The first capturing group will be the width value, and the second is the height value.

To use it practically and assign these captured values how you want, you do this:

```
var height = re.exec('width=611px;height=262px;')[2]; //2 for the second capturing group
var width = re.exec('width=611px;height=262px;')[1]; //1 for the first capturing group
```

```js
var testStr = 'width=611px;height=262px;';
var re = /width=(\d{1,4})px;height=(\d{1,4})px;/;

console.log('Width: %d', Number(re.exec(testStr)[1]));
console.log('Height: %d', Number(re.exec(testStr)[2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

The string is a fixed format, all you need to know is the position of the first `;` - from that you can extract the values based on their offset within the string.  Personally I see no reason to employ a regular expression.

```
var pos = str.indexOf(";");

var w = str.substr(6, pos - 8);
var h = str.substr(pos + 8, str.length - pos - 11);
```

Comment: This isn't a very good approach for unknown sizes. You're hardcoding positional substrings based on 3 digit numbers, but this would fail for any other length.

Comment: var pos = str.indexOf(";");
var w = str.substring(6, pos - 2);
var h = str.substring(pos+8, str.length-3);

Comment: Regex is a better approach as a properly written regex covers better test cases than the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

It partly depends on the reliability of your input data. A significant advantage of a Regex is that it provides a convenient way to validate the format of the whole input string.

Not that I would necessarily recommend this approach for readability concerns, but you can do it as a one-liner using destructuring assignment in Javascript 1.7+:

```
[ , width, height ] = (/width=(\d+)px;height=(\d+)px;/.exec(str) || [0,0,0]).map(Number);
```

Note that `[0,0,0]` is our default fallback in case of an invalid format of the input string.

Full test code:

```
var str = "width=611px;height=262px;",
    width, height;

[ , width, height ] = (/width=(\d+)px;height=(\d+)px;/.exec(str) || [0,0,0]).map(Number);

console.log('Width = ' + width);
console.log('Height = ' + height);
```

Output:

```
Width = 611
Height = 262
```

**Alternate version**

This one is more 'academic':

```
var str = "width=611px;height=262px;",
    size, width, height;

if(size = /width=(\d+)px;height=(\d+)px;/.exec(str)) {
  [ width, height ] = size.slice(1).map(Number);
}
else {
  throw "invalid format";
}
```

**Without Regex**

If your input data is reliable enough and you don't need to check its format, something like that should work just as well:

```
var str = "width=611px;height=262px;",
    width, height;

[ width, height ] = str.split('=').slice(1).map(function(s) { return parseInt(s, 10); });
```